# require works on SSH but doesn't on browser

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, path

I'm trying to use AWS SDK on my project but getting "Failed opening required",

Its very strange becouse the path is pretty right, and if i call the php file from "Putty" it run fine. But if i call from browser i'll get a fatal error on my require instruction.

PHP:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(get_include_path(),'/opt/aws-sdk/')));
require 'aws-autoloader.php';
```

My path from FTP:

```
/opt/aws-sdk/aws-autoloader.php
```

I've tried so differents ways to call this require, but no one works.

Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'aws-autoloader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/opt/aws-sdk/') in /data/vhosts/awxwdna/domains/awx.wdna.com.br/public_html/Conta.php on line 3
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the web server user even have read access to that location?

Comment: What happens if you change it to: `require '/opt/aws-sdk/aws-autoloader.php';` does it work then?

Comment: Yeah, if i change i'll get exactly the same behavior =/

Comment: I'm trying to change the permission to check if is that.

Comment: If you do an `echo get_include_path();` what do you get? Did `set_include_path()` work correctly?

Comment: Also just wondering what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: If i get the include path i'll get /opt/aws-sdk/ and the others include path, it seens right, i'm running 5.3 php, but all poiting to permission issue, until i access it by the SSH and it runs fine.